# Privacy: How to block all google.com and facebook cookies and javascript calls from every site I visit?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

I have started using chrome for accessing google.com services, and firefox for everything else.

I never log in to google services from firefox, and do not want google (or facebook or amazon) tracking anything I do in firefox.

How do I set firefox to always, unconditionally, block any and all access to and from google.com and facebook.com?

(I understand this will break some sites. That does not bother me.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 interesting, thanks! No, the facebook container is for a different use case (isolating the facebook login to a single tab). I do not use facebook. My project here is to prevent other sites from running facebook.com and google.com pieces on my system.

Comment: Use private browsing ...

Comment: @DavidPostill that is a good suggestion. This thread is an effort to go a step beyond that.

Comment: Sounds like you need a combination of Noscript and Ubock Origin ...

Comment: @DavidPostill figures. I had hoped there would be a direct setting or single plugin that would give close to a single click ...

Comment: There are two ways to accomplish this.  The first is to use a third-party DNS provider that gives you the ability to create a blacklist.  The second way is to run a DNS provider within your network, which allows you to create a blacklist, and connect all devices to it.  However, it seems you want us to recommend specific solutions, but questions seeking recommendations are not within scope.

Answer (score 1):

EFF's [Privacy Badger](https://www.eff.org/privacybadger) has a feature that may work for your purposes. You can use it to choose whether certain resources are allowed (green), blocked (red) or loaded 'anonymously' with no cookies being saved (yellow). Privacy Badger claims to automatically adjust its settings as you browse, so it 'learns' which domains might be tracking you. However, you can always manually override it. The example screenshot shows how I've manually set up some domains referenced by this site.

[image: Screenshot of Privacy Badger]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend uMatrix.  It permits blocking (or allowing) by hostname and domain name, as well as viewing what scripts, cookies, etc. are being allowed.  The extension can be found here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/umatrix/

If you're mildly familiar with how web pages work, I suspect you would be able to pick it up.  If you aren't up to speed, it is probably pretty obscure.  I would not recommend it for my parents.